# Proving $\int_a^b (1-x^4) \ dx \le b-a$ when $b>a$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

This is what I did:

$$\int_a^b (1-x^4) \ dx = x-\frac{x^5}{5}|_a^b = b-\frac{b^5}{5}-a+\frac{a^5}{5} = b-a-\left(\frac{b^5}{5}+\frac{a^5}{5}\right)$$

If I can show that $\left(\frac{b^5}{5}+\frac{a^5}{5}\right)$ is always positive then I can show the inequality, but this is not always the case. How can I proceed?

Comment: There is a sign error. Your final expression should be $(b-a)-(\frac{b^5}{5}-\frac{a^5}{5})$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to me everyone is working too hard. Since $x^4\ge 0$, we know $1-x^4\le 1$. Therefore, $$\int_a^b (1-x^4)dx \le \int_a^b 1\,dx=b-a.$$

Comment: That's what I was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

If $b-a>$, then $\frac{b^5}5-\frac{a^5}5>0$. You then have $b-a-c$, where $c=\frac{b^5}5-\frac{a^5}5$. Since $c$ is positive, $b-a-c<b-a$.

Answer (score 0):

As you said:

$$\int_a^b (1-x^4) \ dx = x-\frac{x^5}{5}|_a^b = b-\frac{b^5}{5}-a+\frac{a^5}{5} = 
b-a-\left(\frac{b^5}{5}-\frac{a^5}{5}\right)$$

Since $b>a$, $b^5>a^5$, and thus

$$\left(\frac{b^5}{5}-\frac{a^5}{5}\right)>0$$

so this is $<b-a$.

Comment: $b>a \implies b^5>a^5$ always?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs Yes, since $f(x) = x^5$ is monotonically increasing. Also, note that $$\frac{b^5-a^5}{b-a} = a^4+a^3b+a^2b^2+ab^3+b^4 = \left(a^2+\frac{ab}{2}\right)^2+\left(b^2+\frac{ab}{2}\right)^2+\frac{1}{2}(ab)^2$$ which is a sum of squares of real numbers and thus positive. This is in no way obvious but I think it's kinda cool.